# Laravel query scope - how is $query attributes passed?

Tags: laravel

```
public function scopePublished($query) {

         $query->where('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now());

     }
```

How is the $query parameter passed here? Does the function pass the parameter $query to itself?

Here is the function call:

```
public function index() {

    $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get();

    return view('articles.index', compact('articles'));

}
```

Comment: This isn’t a programming issue. Check out [Laravel’s source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent) if you’re interested in how it works under the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Model class itself passes on everything all missing method calls, except `increment()` and `decrement()`, to the underlying Query object. This is done via magic `__call()` and `__callStatic()` methods.

The Query object, `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, then does this:

```
    if (method_exists($this->model, $scope = 'scope'.ucfirst($method))) {
        return $this->callScope($scope, $parameters);
    }
```

I.e it checks if there is a method with the method name prefixed with scope() available on the model, and if so - it simply calls it and passing it self (i.e the Query).